# SSL certificates for servers behind load balancers

Tags: ssl, nginx, load-balancing, artifactory, docker-registry

I have the following infrastructure for my artifactory web server

```
Artifactory Server - myMainartifactory.myCompany.com
load balancer - myLoadbalancer01.myCompany.com
load balancer - myLoadBlancer02.myCompany.com
```

The SSL certificate is purchased for the domain myMainArtifactory.myCompany.com that both load balancers serve.
From some posts including [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/68753/does-each-server-behind-a-load-balancer-need-their-own-ssl-certificate) one, I was under the impression that I could use the same private key and certificate for the load balancers.
But when I try to ping the docker registry it says that the certificate is for `myMainArtifactory.mycompany.com domain`.
How does this work?